# Return Last 4 Digits of Phone Number in Velocity

Tags: email, velocity, velocity.js

I need to return the last 4 digits of a Phone Number field (where the format isn't consistent) to display as a PIN.

Apologies for my grotesque attempt but what can I change below to display $PIN as the last 4 digits of the phone field?

`#set ($PIN = ${lead.IR_Main_Phone__c}.substring(0,-4))`

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Velocity is not directly Java nor JS (see here:http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/vtl-reference.html).

Unfortunately substring(X,X) works but substring(X,-X) does not work.

Comment: You can try the alternative I posted, without substring, just pure regex

Answer (score 2):

You should filter non-digit characters in **lead.IR_Main_Phone__c** var, then get last 4 digits.

Example:

```
String phoneno = "+1-(800)-555-2468";
$phoneno.replaceAll("\D", ""); //Removes non-digit characters 
$PIN = $phoneno.substring(0,-4) //gives: 2468
```

Also, another way without substring:

```
String phoneno = "+1-(800)-555-2468";
$phoneno.replaceAll("\D", ""); //Removes non-digit characters 
$phoneno.replaceAll("(?=\d{5})\d", ""); //removes all but last 4 digits 
$PIN = $phoneno //gives: 2468
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't velocity an animation library? 
Just use regular javascript

```
var str = "123-4 5 6 7";
var numbersOnly = str.match(/\d+/g, str).join('');
console.log(numbersOnly.length); // outputs 7
console.log(numbersOnly.substr(numbersOnly.length-4)); //output "4567"
```

Edit: now uses regex to filter out non-numbers

Comment: OP wrote that the format is not consistent, so the last four characters could be " 1 2" from "9 8 7 6 1 2". Could you think of a way of using a regex to extract only digits from the string and get the last four?